# C# Regex.Matches - Quotation Marks Problem

Tags: c#, html, regex, screen-scraping

I am new to the community and first wanna introduce myself. My name is Ben and I am loving to code, but I began to code like 2 years ago and coded not really much since now (maybe 50 hours at all).

So my question is the following. I wanna scrape some data from a Website and it works almost perfect, but the problem is, that I have a string in the source code like that:
-> "key":"Name","role" and I want to grab only the Name without any quotation marks. 
Now my code looks like the following:

```
MatchCollection AllChampionName = Regex.Matches(html, @"key\s*(.+?)\s*role", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

But the result in my textbox is like the following text: ":"Name"," 
I know why, but I don't know how I can handle it, because I don't know how regex works.

Can someone pls tell me the right code, so that I only get Name without quotation marks and maybe a source, where I can read more about Regex and how it works with the commands, because I found no good source :(

Edit: I am programming in C#.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Do not use regex to extract data from JSON, use `JSON.NET`. If it is is inside  HTML also use an HTML parser.

Comment: Okay thank you. Didn't know that JSON.NET exist. How do you I can crawl like a part from the html site. I mean the JSON part. It begins with: <script>
  keymaking.data = [and then the JSON file]. I tried to use HTMLAgilityPack, but I don't have a clue how to use it...